# Preparing and cleaning external resources for test runs in Gradle

Tags: gradle

What is the best way to prepare external resources and environment to run e2e tests in Gradle?

I need

1. create db
2. run some server on the db
3. run some test on the server
4. stop the server
5. delete the db.

The best solution for this I've found is
testTask depends on runServerTask.
runServerTask depends on createDbTask.
testTask is finilized by stopServerTask.
stopServerTask is finilized by deleteDbTask.

This way has some disadvantages. If the runServerTask fails, deleteDbTask won't be run.

Is there a better way to manage external resources for test runs?